# Which Z-Move has the highest base power?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Just a bit curious, as to which Z-Move has the highest power. When I say this, I mean in base power, this is not including any other additional effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inferno Overdrive when using [V-create](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/V-create_(move)) has 220 base power, making it the Z-move with the highest possible base power, as well as the second-strongest move after Explosion.

Answer (score 5):

When looking solely at the base power of certain Z-Moves the two strongest are [Catastropika](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Catastropika_(move)) by Pikachu and [Pulverizing pancake](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pulverizing_Pancake_(move)) by Snorlax with a power of 210 each.

Note that only pokemon specific Z-Moves actually have a base power. The type specific ones (such as Breakneck Blitz) will scale off the chosen move. This means that a Breakneck Blitz used through Quick attack will be weaker (BP 100) than a Breakneck Blitz used through Mega Kick (BP 190).

The original attack will be chosen through the Z-Move overlay. As soon as you press the Z-Move button you'll see the overlay and if you have multiple compatible attacks you'll have the same Z-Move multiple times. 
For example: If you have Quick Attack as the first entry on your attack list and Mega Kick as your 3rd you'll see 2 Breakneck Blitz on the 1st and 3rd position.

Another interesting attack in terms of strength is the [Guardian of Alola](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Guardian_of_Alola_(move)) move which deals damage equal to 75% of the opponents current health.

Answer (score -4):

It's obviously either Pulverizing Pancake, Tectonic Rage,or Shattered Psych

Comment: This contradicts the accepted answer that was posted 3 years ago. You can improve your answer by adding your reasonings to why you say they are the strongest Z-moves